# Is there something like VS Solutions in Notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I've been searching around for a while but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  I use Notepad++ quite a lot to write offline SQL queries and XML markup.

I'd like to know if there is a plugin (or a completely different editor out there) that would give Notepad++ functionality similar to VisualStudio's solutions and/or projects.  A tree view of folders and files that are meaningfully grouped together for quick ready access.

Thanks

Comment: Well, Notepad++ is not an IDE. It's just a text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are "project" plugins, but in my experience they do not work very well. I have found that jEdit has better plugins for providing some of the more IDE-oriented capabilities, but like @BoltClock said, Notepad++ is really just a powerful text editor and does not try to be a one-stop-shop IDE. (that is more the role that Eclipse likes to play)

Comment: I'm trying to find a middle ground that I don't think many people find themselves in.  All of my editing and coding has to be done off line, and then copy and pasted in to a query box and executed.  If I had direct access to the database I would just be using SQL Management Studio and be done with it.  So Notepad++'s syntax highlighting is great, but a full fledged IDE (at least SQL ones I've found) assume you have some direct connection to the DB server to help with schema validation.

Comment: @NA Slacker - jEdit has some additional plugins that Notepad++ doesn't, like code completion (to a limited extent at least) that may get you closer to your goal. For example, you could have your DDL open in one document, and then the code-complete would pull from that for table names / fields, etc. I agree though that the options are limited.

Comment: Playing around with jEdit this looks much more like what I had in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about real "projects" but if you just want to see a directory tree inside Notepad++, you might have some luck with the Explorer or Explorer Light plugins. Don't know if this suits your needs though. In the end Notepad++ is text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SolutionHub plugin does a good job. Especially together with "Open file in solution".

http://www.incrediblejunior.com/npp_plugins/